# Change name of many-to-many join table

Tags: go, go-gorm

The join table's name needs to be `UserLanguages`. But GORM always creates the table as `user_languages`.

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Languages []*Language `gorm:"many2many:UserLanguages;"`
}

type Language struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:UserLanguages;"`
}
```

How can I change the name of the join table?

I found [NamingStrategy in GORM's docs](https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NamingStrategy):

> GORM allows users to change the naming conventions by overriding the default NamingStrategy which need to implements interface Namer

But whatever I tried I couldn't get it work. Maybe someone has an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorm will try to convert *CamelCase* to *snake_case* because that's the common naming convention for tables in most databases.

The camel to snake case conversion will also be applied in your case, on the `many2many` table name annotation. E.g.: if you'd use *AaaBbbCccDdd*, you would end up with a join table named *aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd*

To change the default behavior, you can override the `NoLowerCase` value to `true` in the naming strategy of the gorm config.

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/schema"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Languages []*Language `gorm:"many2many:UserLanguages;"`
}
type Language struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string
    Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:UserLanguages;"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("mydb.db"), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            NoLowerCase: true, // << HERE
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Language{})
}
```

---

If you really need to override the JoinTableName method, although you probably don't need to, you can do something as shown below, and you will end up with join table named *UserLanguages_OVERRIDE_HERE*

```golang
type MyCustomNaming struct {
    schema.NamingStrategy
}
func (MyCustomNaming) JoinTableName(table string) string {
    return table + "_OVERRIDE_HERE"
}
func main() {
    ns := MyCustomNaming{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            NoLowerCase: true,
        },
    }
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("mydb.db"), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: ns,
    })
...
```